# Can i put a range for my integer paramater

Tags: checker-framework

Can i put a range for an integer parameter to ensure integer value to be between a given range

```
method(int @Range(0,9) i)
```

which literally checks if parameter i is between those given range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want compile-time checking, you can use the Checker Framework's [Index Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#index-checker) or [Constant Value Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#constant-value-checker) and write an [`@IntRange`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/common/value/qual/IntRange.html) annotation:

```
method(int @IntRange(0,9) i) { ... }
```

Comment: im having trouble at adding checker framework to my project by maven. It says cant resolve this symbol <annotatedJdk>${org.checkerframework:jdk8:jar}</annotatedJdk> at maven properties section what is the problem?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue.  I suggest that you open a new question, which will enable you to provide a complete, reproducible test case.